# Issue in axios in reactjs

Tags: axios

I am using axios. My code is like below. I am getting output when I am using `console.log()`.

```
axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/addresses?page=' + this.state.val,{
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + Auth.getToken(),
        },})
    .then(function (response) {

        //console.log(response.data.data); // I am getting output here

        this.setState({result: response.data.data});  // TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined 
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

Comment: `var self = this; axios.get(...<snip>... self.setState`. Here `this` refer to the function context it's written in.  You can probably get around it using an es6 arrow-function as well.

Comment: Thanks @ippi. Your solution is working. Thanks again.